# How to handle issue with connecting participants in a twilio conference?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Generally when I do direct call via `<Dial><Number>` Twiml, I used to listen the ringing and network message if the caller is busy or not answering or switched off. Maybe that's because I had used `answerOnBridge=true`?

Now I am starting a call from web client, putting myself in a conference, then creates a REST call to the caller. At that time, I only get to listen the `wait` music of the conference since I am alone in the conference. Nothing happens when the caller doesn't pickup or hang up without answering, it just keeps playing the music. I am using REST call with `url` to link the conference but that only happens when the user picks up.

```
  return client.calls
    .create({
      from: from,
      to: to,
      url: callbackUrl,
      statusCallback: 'https://xx.m.pipedream.net/',
      statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated',
        'ringing', 'answered',
        'completed']
    });
```

I know I can use the `statusCallback` to get the status and broadcast a message probably, but is there any other way to make this feel more natural and get the real network message that we usually get when we call via cellphone? Thanks!

Note: I have intention to add or transfer to users, so I need to use conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the /Call resource, use the [conference participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) end-point (Create A Participant) to be able to listen to the call progress tones (earlyMedia).

[image]

Comment: That seems to work! @Alan Is it going to be heard by all connected participants when someone adds in a new participant?

Comment: Yes, everyone will hear the call progress tones. It may be possible to look at trying to modify the behavior by manipulating the conference participant legs somehow but I’ve not personally tried.

Answer (score 0):

@Alan earlyMedia=true only seems to work for conferences that are already started (at least 2 participants), if there is only one participant (the agent) waiting for the other participant to join, the agent does not hear the call progress tones but the hold music